# how to output each loop vector

Tags: r, for-loop

there are 5 persons data (subject 1,3,5,7,9),

I subset it by the condition of block
 (block(1:12),block(51:62),block(101:112)),

to output my exactly wanted value ---- 'Respond',which I used it to count otherthings.

here is the example of subject 1,

---

[

```html
respond Subject Session Block
3.00  1 1 1
2.00  1 1 2
3.00  1 1 3
3.00  1 1 4
2.00  1 1 5
3.00  1 1 6
1.00  1 1 7
3.00  1 1 8
1.00  1 1 9
2.00  1 1 10
3.00  1 1 11
1.00  1 1 12
2.00  1 1 51
2.00  1 1 52
2.00  1 1 53
1.00  1 1 54
3.00  1 1 55
2.00  1 1 56
2.00  1 1 57
3.00  1 1 58
2.00  1 1 59
3.00  1 1 60
1.00  1 1 61
1.00  1 1 62
3.00  1 1 101
1.00  1 1 102
3.00  1 1 103
1.00  1 1 104
2.00  1 1 105
3.00  1 1 106
2.00  1 1 107
1.00  1 1 108
3.00  1 1 109
3.00  1 1 110
2.00  1 1 111
1.00  1 1 112
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1ZeE.jpg)

---

finally, it will be presented like that as a matrix for each subject(5)

```html
(block1:12--respond)  
3.00    
2.00 
3.00 
3.00 
2.00 
3.00 
1.00 
3.00 
1.00 
2.00 
3.00 
1.00 

 (block51:62--respond) 
 2.00 
2.00 
2.00 
1.00 
3.00 
2.00 
2.00 
3.00 
2.00 
3.00 
1.00 
1.00 

 
 (block101:112--respond)  
3.00 
1.00 
3.00 
1.00 
2.00 
3.00 
2.00 
1.00 
3.00 
3.00 
2.00 
1.00
```

---

### programming(1)

```
subject <- c(1,3,5,7,9)
for i in length (subject) {
     data（i）<- list(
          sub_1_RT<-subset(data, subject == i & block ==(1:12),'Respond'),
          sub_2_RT<-subset(data, subject == i & block ==(51:62),'Respond'),             
  )
  print（data）
}
```

### programming 2

```
 for (i in c(1,3,5,7,9)) {
   mydata<- list(
                sub_1 <- subset(sub45,sub45$Subject == 'i' 
                         & sub45$Session == '1'
                         & sub45$Block == (1:12),'Respond'),
                sub_2 <- subset(sub45,sub45$Subject == 'i' 
                         & sub45$Session == '1'
                         & sub45$Block == (51:62),'Respond'),

   )
   print(mydata)
}
```

Comment: This kind of seems like splitting your data: You need to create splitting factors: eg split the iris datatable with species and also the rows ie 1:10,11:20 etc.. you can do `by(iris,iris[5],split,f=rep(1:10,each=5))`

Comment: One thing that can really help people to help you is to show what your expected results are for a small sample of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to create a sample dataset for myself so i can run your code over it(You can ignore this line).

```
blocks<-cbind((1:12),(51:62),(101:112))
dt<-data.frame(Respond= sample(1:3,112,replace = T),Subject=sample(1:10,112,replace = T),
               Session=sample(1:4,112,replace = T), Block=sample(blocks, 112,replace = T ))
```

And then `subset` it:

```
print("block: 1:12--respond")
 subset(dt, Subject  %in% c(1,3,5,7,9) & Block %in% (1:12), Respond   ) 
print("block: 51:62--respond")
 subset(dt, Subject  %in% c(1,3,5,7,9) & Block %in% (51:62), Respond   )
print("block101:112--respond")
 subset(dt, Subject  %in% c(1,3,5,7,9) & Block %in% (101:112), Respond   )
```